# JQuery / Javascript: Function not calling within document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What I want to do is have a slider where DIVs move left & right. The code looks as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $slider;
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

 $(function() {
    $slider = $('.slidemid');
    $slider.fadeOut();

    // set active classes
    $slider.first().addClass('active');
    $slider.first().fadeIn($transition_time).css('display', 'inline-block');

    // auto scroll 
    setInterval(function () {
      slideright(); }, $transition_time + $time_between_slides );

    $('.slidelefta').click(function() {slideleft(); return false;});
    $('.sliderighta').click(function() {slideright(); return false;});

 });

 function slideright() {
 $slider = $('.slidemid');
  var $i = $slider.find('.active').index();

  $slider.eq($i).removeClass('active');
  $slider.eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

  if ($slider.length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

  $slider.eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time).css('display', 'inline-block');
  $slider.eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
}
function slideleft() {
 $slider = $('.slidemid');
  var $i = $slider.find('.active').index();

  $slider.eq($i).removeClass('active');
  $slider.eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

  if ($i == 0) $i = $slider.length; // loop to end

  $slider.eq($i - 1).fadeIn($transition_time).css('display', 'inline-block');
  $slider.eq($i - 1).addClass('active');
}

</script>
```

The initial `fadeOut`, `fadeIn` and `addClass` (in the `document.ready` function) get executed just fine.

The calls to `slideright()` and `slideleft()` never get executed though.

Comment: Does the console show up any error?

Comment: Do you mean both the call setup in `setInterval` and the `click` handlers?

Comment: First of all, I'm not sure why you're getting the next and previous and current elements using eq(), there are existing functions for that. Secondly, the code within the document.ready section looks fine, so probably your slideleft/right functions are bad

Comment: Also, how do you know they aren't executed? Or is it that they are executed, but just aren't doing what you expect? Did you set a breakpoint in the function(s)?

Comment: @redShadow is absolutely right about checking your console. That's should be your first step. [jsHint](http://www.jshint.com) should be your second. Once you've gotten the gremlins worked out there, SO can be of better assistance : )

Comment: Without seeing your HTML and CSS this is going to be hard to tackle.

Comment: Thank you all. The console shows no error. i mean both setInterval and click. the eq() is something i copy/pasted from an existing solution, I will change that. The functions do not get executed (i manually added onClick events, and set breakpoints in firebug). The CSS shouldn't be needed (there's nothing there), the HTML is "<div class=".slidemid">what'stherehey</div>", so nothing exciting either.

Comment: Thank you for the jsHint tip - I was looking for something like that for a while while trying to debug my script. Anyways, all it says is that it misses "use strict", the rest is working fine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ijanaf) where i pasted your code and simplified some of the lines since the invocation of the defined functions was the problem. You can see there, in the console, that
in fact the function is being called from the setInterval. Also, i want to point here that it's better to define your functions inside your scope like the way they are declared on the JSBin demo. Why? Well if you define them outside your scope, in the global scope, a very bad person can execute in the console `slideright = function () { evilXSShere; }` and voilà, your function was overwritten.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting the any errors on the console, then I think its the issue of javascript scopes. As you are invoking the functions slideright() and sildeleft() inside the functions of anonymous function, but these functions are defined outside the anonymous function within global scope.

Think that anonymous function as a class and you are invoking the function inside the class functions and those function does not belong to that class scope.

Solution(I haven't confirmed the code, the I am pretty sure that should work):

1. Define those functions inside the anonymous function $(function() or
2. Wrap those function in the constructor function or object

   function slide(){ 
     this.slideRight = function(){} 
     this.slideLeft =  function(){}

   } 
    //invoke it like this 
    var slider = new Slide(); 
    slider.slideRight//for slideRight 
    slider.slideLeft// for slideLeft